# Codeigniter htaccess rewriterules

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, localhost

I'm trying to short my webpage's url with the rewriterules with codeigniter.

I've got in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ci/
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)?$ index.php/controller/method/$1
```

But seems my application ignores all.

I put:

```
http://localhost/ci/variable
```

and error page is displayed:

Object not found error 404.

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` is also not commented.

I've done it in a simple project and seem it works, but not with my codeigniter.

Can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Thanks.

SOLVED ON:

```
Adding RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)?$ /ci/index.php/controller/method/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Is that your real code? /controller/method/ shouldnt be like that. its /*nameOfYourController*/*nameOfYourMethod*/

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ci/
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)?$ index.php/anunciants/mostra/$1

this is my real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a controller named `Controller` with a method named `method`, this line will fail:

```
index.php/controller/method/$1
```

Try something like this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Remember, the way that CodeIgniter processes requests is that it splits everything which happens after the script name (index.php) using `/` as a delimiter. It then starts searching for a controller based on that array. Since I bet you have no `Controller` controller, and no `Controller_Method` controller, CodeIgniter will summarily stick its tongue out at you and refuse to cooperate.

Comment: I've just set the full path of the function and it's not working so well.

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)?$ /ci/index.php/anunciants/mostra/$1

If I put it to go to:

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)?$ /test/

it's working.

Comment: What happens if you navigate to that URL?

Comment: If I go to :

localhost/ci/index.php/anunciants/mostra/asdf

it show me the asdf page

when I put : localhost/ci/asdf it's going on a 404 error page.

Comment: The error was not putting the [L,R=301]code.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put the htaccess file in your root folder for your local server

ie.

if WAMP put it in wamp/www/.htacess

or if XAMPP put it in xampp/htdocs/.htaccess

Comment: I moved the file from the htdocs/ci/application to htdocs/ci and it seems it runs now, but also get error message.

404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

This is the default CI 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is in the folder `/ci`, i.e. .htaccess, index.php, then your `RewriteRule` should just work.

If `index.php` is in the root directory, you add a leading slash

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)?$ /index.php/controller/method/$1
```

If `.htaccess` is in the root directory as well, remove `RewriteBase` and prepend `ci` to your `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ci/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)?$ /index.php/controller/method/$1
```

If nothing of these work, specify exactly where each file is located, i.e. where is .htaccess, where is index.php.

Comment: Files:

I've got this tree:

-htdocs
-- ci
---- application
------.htaccess(the default one)
------ controllers and views(all codeigniter system)
---- index.php
----.htaccess(I moved the first here cause was ignored)
-- test (another project)